# Specify the lines of textfield to display

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to make a preview of my article. How to select first several lines of  `TextField`? I am using the flask and wtforms.

```
class Blog(Model):
    content = TextField()
```

template:

```
{{blog.content}}
```

But how to specify the first several lines to display? For example, only display 4 lines. `blog.content(rows = 4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `blog.content` consists of lines separated by newline characters, you can just split the content by newline and return the first four elements, joined:

```
>>> content = 'One\nTwo\nThree\nFour\nFive\nSix'
>>> parts = content.split('\n')
>>> preview = '\n'.join(parts[:4])
>>> preview      # use this in the template {{ preview }}
'One\nTwo\nThree\nFour'
```

If `blog.content` does not consist of lines separated by newline characters, you could use jinja2's [truncate](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#truncate) filter, which will output the first n *characters* of `blog.content`, where n is some number that you choose.  If truncation occurs in the middle of a word, `truncate` will discard that word.

```
{{ blog.content|truncate(100) }}
```